# Observe Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this to invoke a function when a form on the page is submitted:

```
$$("form").invoke("observe", "submit", submitForm);
```

I'm having a problem getting this to work in IE when a text field has focus and the enter key is pressed.  Firefox submits the form in this case but not IE.

The form has one submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Clicking the submit button works fine in both browsers using this method.

Comment: I think there is more code needed, the whole form and submitForm too.

Comment: If you really want to submit the form when someone pushes enter you shoud handle onkeydown event on texarea and check what key was pressed. If it is enter, you should submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

I had the form inside of a `<div style="display:none">` and for some reason just removing the display none did the trick.  This was actually a JSP with other hidden forms using AJAX calls to control which form was displayed.

I should have posted more code than I did.  Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Jquery what you might want is:

```
$(yourInputElem).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
         document.forms["yourFormHere"].submit();
     }
}
```

This then should submit the form for that input elem in IE.